# Confused about tags

Tags: templating, routes, tags

I'm tried to following the how-to implement tags but can't see to get it to work.
The how-to: https://craftcms.com/support/tag-urls

I created a new route, and in the URI field, I entered:

```
tags/( ‘tag’ token )
```

In the template field I entered:

```
tags/_tag
```

I created a folder in my template folder called tags and placed the template html file called:

```
_tags.html
```

_tags.html contains the following:

```
{% extends "_layout" %}
{% block content %}
    {% set tag = craft.tags.title(tag).first() %}

    <h1>Entries tagged with "{{ tag.title }}"</h1>

{% set entries = craft.entries.relatedTo(tag).order('title') %}

{% if entries | length %}
    <ul>
        {% for entry in entries %}
            <li>{{ entry.getLink() }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% else %}
    <p>No entries could be found with that tag.</p>
{% endif %} 
{% endblock %}
```

In my entry template, at the bottom, I have this snippet to list all related tags and to hyperlink those tags.

```
{% if entry.tags | length %}
    <h4>Tags</h4>
    <ul>
    {% for tag in entry.tags %}
        <li><a href="{{ siteUrl }}tags/{{ tag.title | url_encode }}" title="{{ tag.title }}">{{ tag.title }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endif %}
```

An example of my entry is located below. It correctly shows the tag called 'Platformer'
http://www.colorcomputergames.com/games/donkey-king

The URL, looks good.
http://www.colorcomputergames.com/tags/Platformer

But when I go to the url, I get a 404

Cheers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You told Craft to look for `tags/_tag`

And then you created `templates/tags/_tags.html`

Note you have no `s` on the end in the route definition, but you do in the template name.

Comment: Oops, that was a typo. The route is tags/( ‘tag’ token ) and tags/_tags. The template file is tags.html. But not working. Still get a 404.

Comment: BTW, I am following this tutorial: https://craftcms.com/support/tag-urls

Comment: Ok next guess - did you actually use the tag token (from the UI list of available tokens), or did you actually type or copy `tags/( ‘tag’ token )`

Comment: Uhg! Yeah, I copied and pasted tags/( ‘tag’ token )!! That's an easy mistake for a newbie!!I changed it to: tags/* I figure that means anything that starts with tags/ and any text after the / to route. Last thing to fix is {{ tag.title }}, as it isn't displaying. Also, it is showing ALL games with a tag, rather than JUST the game (entries) that use the tag. (See link in original post)